# jQuery .replaceWith only once for each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Running into an issue with something I've written, still not great with jQuery so I'm not sure how to fix.

```
$("a[href=##]").replaceWith("<label>" + $("a[href=##]").text() + "</label>");
```

This will generate a simple label for me, but my issue is that if I have multiple links with the href value of ##, the text of **each** link will populate the label for **all** instances.

For example, if I have this:

```
<a href="##">Foo</a>
<a href="##">Bar</a>
```

The result will be:

```
<label>FooBar</label>
<label>FooBar</label>
```

When I'd obviously like it to be:

```
<label>Foo</label>
<label>Bar</label>
```

I've tried a few things, but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $("a[href=##]").each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith("<label>" + $(this).text() + "</label>");
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TLPPw/2/)**

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew it couldn't be too difficult. Will accept in a few minutes when I'm allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to replace with :

```
$("a[href=##]").replaceWith(function(){
    return "<label>" + $(this).text() + "</label>";
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLPPw/4/)**

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Jeez, i was too hasty, Thank for pointing out my mistake!